# How to access the iPhone gallery folders programmatically in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am working on a photo backing app in Xamarin for iphone.I need to get the folder paths of the folders in gallery,so that i can save the paths of the folders selected by the user in sqlite and backup the selected folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, apps are only allowed to access directory that are not within there own sandbox.

If you where doing it in Objective-C you could have used the ALAssest framework to get access to the images.